# Image Sizes and Android

Tags: android, graphics, imageview, image

I'm trying to create a splash screen of sorts for my Android App but am having problems getting the image to fill the screen (too tall, too skinny, etc). Instead of messing around recreating the image a million times to find the correct dimensions I was wondering if there is a "standard image size" that I should use for each screen density if I want it to properly fill the entire screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the image stretchable using [draw-9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html). You will probably still need a few different image sizes but this way your images should be able to stretch without getting distorted for screen sizes you aren't expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah the Android docs has all of this relevant information in the: [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) section. There is a table in there that should specify all of the different screen sizes that you will need to account for.